# How to add a Java tier in AppDynamics

Tags: java, appdynamics

I have a project that I'm monitoring in AppDynamics for which a python process with a tier that I can read in AppDynamics it's already working.
Now I want to add a new Java tier to get more info from the Java part of my application
My configuration is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<controller-info>
    <controller-host>my host url</>
    <account-access-key>my key</account-access-key>
    <controller-port>443</controller-port>
    <controller-ssl-enabled>on</controller-ssl-enabled>
    <application-name>myapplication</application-name>
    <account-name>myaccount</account-name>
    <node-name>mynode</node-name>
    <tier-name>mytier</tier-name>
</controller-info>
```

This configuration is the same that I'm using in the Python part, except for the node-name and tier-name.

I've created in AppDynamics a new tier in the `Tiers & Nodes` ->
`Create App Server Tier`

Now when I launch my application in a Dockerfile with an entrypoint like:
`['java', '-javaagent:/opt/appdynamics/ver22.4.0.33722/javaagent.jar', '-jar', 'application.jar]`

I 'm having errors,  In agent-initial*.log :

```
APM Agent present: Yes
APM Agent enabled: It is Enabled
APM Agent status: It is not registered!!!
APM Agent version: Server Agent #22.4.0.33722 v22.4.0 GA compatible with 4.4.1.0 rb331a334461edd5eb1d77f0c99bec1f876202683 release/22.4.0
Argento Agent startup status: Not Started!!!
Argento Agent enabled status: No
Auth Service status: Is Broken
```

and in agent.*.log :

```
ERROR ConfigurationChannel - Fatal transport error while connecting to URL <URL> java.net.UnknownHostException: <host> Name or service not known
```

the url is the same that I'm using in the other project so it should be able to be found.
Another error log, from argentoDynamicService*.log

```
https: Name or service not known Response Code: 0
```

It really looks like the host can't be reached, but in the other application there is no problem at all. Do you know if I'm missing something in the configuration here or there is something else that I need to take into account?

Comment: <controller-host> should have just the host name and not the protocol. Can you double check on this. Should be something like <controller-host>10.0.0.1</controller-host>

Comment: Do I need to use the IP? Can't I use the DNS?

Comment: You can use DNS.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least two errors in your config (missing correct closing tag, incorrect ssl flag).

Given a controller of https://mycontroller.saas.appdynamics.com/, your settings should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<controller-info>
    <controller-host>mycontroller.saas.appdynamics.com</controller-host>
    <account-access-key>ACCESS_KEY_TAKEN_FROM_LICENSE_SCREEN_IN_CONTROLLER</account-access-key>
    <controller-port>443</controller-port>
    <controller-ssl-enabled>true</controller-ssl-enabled>
    <application-name>APPLICATION_NAME</application-name>
    <account-name>mycontroller</account-name>
    <node-name>NODE_NAME</node-name>
    <tier-name>TIER_NAME</tier-name>
</controller-info>
```

Also note that Argento is for Cisco Secure Application, which can be ignored (unless of course you are licensed for this product)